# How can I get the Razer Spectre to auto change profile?

Tags: mouse

I got this gaming mouse for Christmas and I've been fiddling with the profile settings but it won't change colour. For example, I set a profile for VLC, but when I open it nothing happens. Do I set it to the process exe or run exe?

Comment: Why not try both, and see which works?

Comment: @MBraedley that article is for a Cyborg RAT rather than a Razer Spectre, the Razer software does support auto profile switching.

Comment: @pixel yes thank you, I realize that now.  I saw "mouse profile switch" and immediately thought of my older question.

Comment: @Ioan this looks to be a case of creating a profile and setting the application executable to watch for in order to change profile, although I do not have any Razer hardware so cannot test this for you. When you save your profile you will want to select vlc.exe (for your test example) and this should then change your profile when you start up vlc.